# Is username and password mandatory for JDBC connection using tableau?

Tags: jdbc, db2, tableau-api

I was trying to connect to IBM DB2 warehouse using tableau via a JDBC connection. I was able to connect to source using url,port,username and password, but then do we have a way where we can provide an API key/Access token instead of an username and password ?.

Tried out a JDBC connection on DBeaver with the url `jdbc:db2://<host>:<port>/BLUDB:apikey=<api key>;securityMechanism=15;pluginName=IBMIAMauth;sslConnection=true;` and was able to make a successful connection, but when tried a similar thing on tableau i am getting the following error `An error occurred while communicating with Other Databases (JDBC) Invalid username or password. Error Code: 37CE01A3 [jcc][t4][2020][11256][4.27.25] Connection authorization failure occurred.  Reason: Invalid GSSAPI server credential. ERRORCODE=-4214, SQLSTATE=28000 Generic JDBC connection error Invalid username or password.`
The problem is i am trying to authenticate using API key without any username and password yet i get an error saying `Invalid username or password.`

I tried giving the properties in a db2.properties file instead of giving them in the url, even that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using tableau desktop, it may use ODBC (also known as CLI in Db2) interface (i.e. a non-java / non-jdbc interface).

Yes you can use an access-token or API-key  with CLI applications in addition to jdbc applications, as long as you are using an IBM supplied Db2-driver and you configure it correctly.

Your IBM Db2 driver needs to be modern, at least v11.1FP3 or preferably higher.

This is a configuration matter, not really programming.

It requires you to configure your IBM Db2 client configuration file called `db2dsdriver.cfg`
which is a small XML file stored on the workstation where the Db2-client runs. It defines your DSNs and in particular it can give various attributes including:

```
<parameter name="Authentication" value="GSSPLUGIN"/>

<parameter name="SecurityTransportMode" value="SSL"/>
```

Please see the instructions at [this](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFMBX/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.security.doc/doc/iam.html) page

To verify the connection, use the `db2cli validate -connect -dsn ...` command line as instructed in the Knowledge Centre.

Then in the connection string (for tableau), you reference the DSN that is defined previously in the `db2dsdriver.cfg` along with the accesstoken, or API-key, (or old style uid/pwd if using).

From that page:

The ODBC connection string can contain one of the following:

Access token

```
DSN=<dsn>;ACCESSTOKEN=<access_token>
```

API key

```
DSN=<dsn>;APIKEY=<api_key>
```

IBMid/password

```
DSN=<dsn>;UID=<ibmid>;PWD=<password>
```

For ODBC, the AUTHENTICATION=GSSPLUGIN can be specified in either the db2dsdriver.cfg configuration file or in the application’s connection string.